# What shape is defined by plotting two loops through 4-dimensional space

Tags: geometry

If I plot two "loops", as defined by

$\ x = r_0*\cos(\theta)$
$\ y = r_0*\sin(\theta)$
$\ z = r_1*\cos(\phi) $
$\ w = r_1*\sin(\phi)$

What shape does this create? It appears to be similar to this picture of two cylinders perpendicular to each other.

[image: http://ronvalstar.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/sketchCylinders.jpg]

(image courtesy of [Ron Valstar](http://ronvalstar.nl/creating-tileable-noise-maps))

However, that is not an adequate description. It also seems to share some similarities with a torus, but without any distortion.

Comment: what is `phi` and `theta`? Are they as spherical coords.?

Comment: I think you could describe them as polar coordinates? I'm working with this in code, so for example `theta` equates to `s = x/dimW; s2PI = s*2.0*PI; vX = xRadius*sin(s2PI); vY = xRadius*cos(s2PI);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $r_0$ and $r_1$ are constants. Then, it's a torus.

Here's a simple shortcut that, while it doesn't always work, can help in "nice" cases like this. How many input variables do you have? In this case, there's two, $\theta$ and $\phi$. That means your output shape should have two dimensions, like a surface.

Second, those two pairs of axes ($x,y$ and $z,w$) are completely independent of each other, and they each sketch out an $S^1$ manifold, or a circle. You can think of all the different pairings of those circles as the output of this plot. In other words, it's $S^1 \times S^1$. That's exactly a torus.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I was thrown a bit by how a torus on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) is defined in 3D space and the differences between the parametric equation there and the one I have. Although now that I re-read it the [Flat torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus) section is exactly what I just asked.